# How to capture Point Clouds and save them in to a PCD file

Tags: c++

I want to capture Point Clouds of real 3D objects in a room , and then i want to save the x, y, z values of each point cloud in a pcd file. I saw the tutorial of PCL documentation , but this tutorial generates random values for x,y,z. Please help

Comment: The first step would be obtaining hardware capable of such 3d scanning. Or do you already have that? If so, it probably came with some documentation and APIs. Have you studied those?

Comment: I can capture Point Clouds from META's 2 IR camera, but i need to know how i can convert and store the x, y, z pcd values of each point cloud in to a pcd file.

Comment: Have you looked at [some PCD format documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php)?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't help me to understand how to store my own point clouds x,y,z values. I know what these 3 values refer to but i want to find a way in order to store my values instead of random values. .

Comment: It's totally unclear what your problem is. You said you can capture point clouds from your camera. What data does that give you, in what format? Your question doesn't even contain the basic information of what hardware you have, let alone how it's accessible programmatically.

Comment: If you already know how to receive x,y,z values from the IR camera and you already know of an example of how random values can be stored into a PCD file then is it not just a matter of substituting the random values with your own? If that's not the case then please clarify. http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php

Comment: Well to be more specific and clear, i have Meta 2 AR headset , and i have this example script witch renders and captures point clouds MetaPointCloudExample.cs.
Secondly i have this script in PCL pcd_write.cpp that saves cloud points exactly as i want but its random points. 
So i want to put my cloud points that Meta 2 renders in this PCD file in x y z values.